# Simple way to run sqlplus script from java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I've got sql file that contains sqlplus specific script: it includes / or ; as statement terminators, EXEC to execute stored procedures, etc.

I need to execute this script from java (jdbc) without the need for sqlplus.

sql ant task / maven sql plugin can't handle the different terminators or EXEC commands.

Do you know any good way to do so without running sqlplus ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've bumped into the same problem... In brief, there are no ready solutions for that: if you open [Ant](http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document-2/Database/solidbase/solidbase/core/SQLSource.java.htm) or [Maven](http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/tags/sql-maven-plugin-1.5/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/sql/SqlSplitter.java) sources, you'll see they are using a simple regexp-based script splitter which is fine for simple scripts, but usually fails on e.g. stored procedures.

There are indeed ANTLR parsers for PL/SQL, such as [Alexandre Porcelli's one](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser)—those are very close, but still not ready to be used as a drop-in solution.

We ended up writing [yet another ad hoc splitter](https://github.com/gxa/gxa/blob/9b93279d2ecda588c517dbe9dfc9f1546f4ad25a/atlas-updates/src/main/java/uk/ac/ebi/gxa/db/OracleScriptSplitter.java) which is aware of some sqlplus commands like `/` and `EXIT`— it's still ugly, but works for most of our scripts.

Comment: Big up for your ad hoc splitter!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options.  One you don't want - to Runtime.exec() it to sqlplus.  The other is to read in the file removing end of line slashes and sending to JDBC when you hit a semicolon.  Or adding to a batch when that happens to reduce trips to the database.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, but I need a good SQLPLUS-like parser that will split the entire file to smaller parts. Simple split by / or ; chars won't work