# Is their any way to connect to oracle database via UNIX shell without using sqlplus

Tags: database-administration, unix, unixodbc

is there any command string in unix which will provide access to oracle database. i **dont want** to use sqlplus command.

thanks for help...

Comment: Do you want to run SQL commands once connected? Or do you just want to check if the database is reachable?

Comment: i just want unix command to connect to database without using sqlplus

Comment: And what do you want to do, once you are connected?

Comment: i need to run procedures and ldt files etc after connecting..

Comment: So what is wrong with SQL*Plus then? (And what are "*ldt files*"?)

Comment: when i am running through java it is not detecting sqlplus command but through unix i am able to execute directly

Comment: So this is actually a Java problem when calling sqlplus...

Answer (score 0):

SQLPlus has its own commands as well as being able to issue SQL and run PROCs. If Java is your thing, try SQL Developer [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocombr) from Oracle - a great full-featured tool. You can also look [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/sql-clients) for open source clients - I can personally recommend SQuirreL SQL and SQL Workbench isn't bad (I've only really looked at it, YMMV).
You might also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923482/simple-way-to-run-sqlplus-script-from-java) question. Maybe an example of what you're trying to do might help?
HTH, Paul...